# Multiprovider: A xxxx was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter

I have a list of kids within the family. I want to update some widgets based on the selection from within the family list (i.e. change on KidFamilyModel). And also update some widgets based on the changes on the concrete selected kid (i.e. on change on KidModel).

I am trying to use the provider state management.

Following exception is thrown after a while when switching between screens / tabs where it is used as `Provider.of<KidModel>(context)` in the build functions:

> The following assertion was thrown building
>   _NumericProxyProvider(dependencies: [InheritedProvider], state:
>   _ProxyProviderState#65f15):
>
> A KidModel was used after being disposed.

I do not understand how it can be disposed as I am not calling any dispose on that.

App state build function:

```dart
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<KidFamilyModel>(
              builder: (context) => KidFamilyModel(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<KidFamilyModel, KidModel>(
              builder: (context, value, previous) => value.selectedKid,
            ),
          child: MaterialApp( ....
```

KidFamilyModel relevant parts

```
 class KidFamilyModel with ChangeNotifier {
    List<KidModel> _kids = [];
    int _selectedKid = 0;

 ...
 KidModel get selectedKid => _kids[_selectedKid];

 void select(int id) {
    assert (id != null);
    assert (id < totalKids && id >= 0);
    _selectedKid = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }
 ...
```

KidModel relevant parts

```
  class KidModel with ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  set uiColor(Color color) {
    _uiColor = color;
    print ("zmena v modelu barvy");
    notifyListeners();
  }
  ...
```

Comment: And there is no problem with the usage of KidFamilyModel.

Comment: This happens mostly because you need to provide the bloc one up level in the tree hierarchy

Comment: the Multiprovider is at the very top